# Destructured rest variable contains other fields as `never` type and cannot be used in assignment directly

Tags: wso2, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

Check the following ballerina code

```
type Student record {|
    string name;
    string school;
|};

type HolidayRequest record {|
    record {|
        *Student;
        int noOfDays;
    |} student;
    string teacher;
|};

function testFn(HolidayRequest req) {
    record {|*Student; int noOfDays;|} {noOfDays, ...studentData} = req.student;
    Student student = {...studentData};
    // undefined field 'noOfDays' in record 'Student'
}
```

The type of `studentData` is `record {|never noOfDays?; string name; string school;|}` and we cannot pass this as a rest field for variable typed `record {|string name; string school;|};`. Why we are not allowing this?

I have tried manually adding the values of the fields separately, but that's not the way I want.

Update:

- Updated the title of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/41363) when using a record with `never`-typed optional fields in a spread field.

A workaround in this scenario would be to use the mapping value via an equivalent static type that does not have `never`-typed fields.

```
Student s1 = studentData;
Student s2 = {...s1};
```